# How to find, return and remove the maximum value from an array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I would like to find the max value in an array of integers, return that value, and remove it from the array. Is there a built in function for this?

For `a = [1,2,3,4]`, I can easily do this `a.max` which returns `4`. However, `a[....]` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.delete(a.max)
=> 4
a => [1, 2, 3]
```

To delete a single instance if there are duplicates you could use something like (As per the comments, use a.index(a.max) to get the index of the max value)

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
a.delete_at(a.index(a.max))
=> 4
a => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: great suggestion, however, for a = [1,2,3,4,4]. a.delete(a.max) returns 4. And both 4's are removed from the array. Not quite what I'm after. It would be great if it returned a single 4 and a single 4 was remove from the array. Then it would be perfect.

Comment: @matthewalexander, good call.  I've updated to handle that.  It should work as it deletes by index, not by value.

Comment: Try your second solution on the return array [1,2,3,4] you will find it fails because there is nothing at index 4. delete_at requires that you pass in the index of the value you want to delete. We are getting closer!

Comment: you can do `a.delete_at(a.index(a.max))`

Comment: Thanks @davidhu2000, I was just cooking that up.  It feels a bit dirty though. `a.delete_at(a.index(a.max))`.  Updating answer.  I do like using the max and delete methods as they are easy to read but sort.pop may be a good way to go to. Might have some adverse side-effects potentially?

Comment: if you use `pop` method, then return value is the value that is removed from the array, and not the array itself.

Comment: delete_at also returns the value that has been removed from the array

Comment: @davidhu2000 but if you use `sort!` it sorts in place. At least it works in my console.

Comment: the return value of the `pop` method is still the number that is removed, i think OP wants to return the adjusted array, you can do `a = a.sort[0..-2]`

Answer (score 4):

Benchmarks:

```
require 'fruity'

ARY = (0..99).to_a.shuffle

compare do
  matthewalexander { a = ARY.dup; a.delete_at(a.index(a.max)) }
  sagarpandya82    { a = ARY.dup; a.sort!.pop                 }
end

# >> Running each test 512 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> sagarpandya82 is faster than matthewalexander by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
```

Increasing the size of ARY will change the results:

```
ARY = (0..999_999).to_a.shuffle

compare do
  matthewalexander { a = ARY.dup; a.delete_at(a.index(a.max)) }
  sagarpandya82    { a = ARY.dup; a.sort!.pop                 }
end

# >> Running each test once. Test will take about 5 seconds.
# >> matthewalexander is faster than sagarpandya82 by 3x ± 0.1
```

Use the appropriate approach for your given needs. If you don't know the size of the array I'd recommend assuming your data will grow since they're so close with small arrays.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
a.sort!.pop #=> 4
```

Comment: Great suggestion - is it necessary to do a sort? Is this more efficient than the answer I posted?

Comment: `sort!` ensures you're `pop`ing a max value, so I'd say leave it, unless you know for sure your array is already sorted in which case you can just use `pop`. For efficiency, I guess you'll have to run some benchmarks...:)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
a.delete_at(a.index(a.max))
```